# $_POST Giving Empty values

Tags: php, html, post

I have an HTML Form and I am trying to get the values from the form in my php file.

```
            <div id="qForm">
            <form action="postComment.php" method="post" name="comment">
            Name: <input type="text" name="askerName"><br>
            Title: <input type="text" name="qTitle"><br>
            <textarea maxlength="255" name="theQ"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
            </form>
            </div>
```

My PHP file looks like this but It echos as Welcome

```
    <?php
     $name = $_POST["askerName"];
     echo $name; //this works
     $textArea = $_POST["theQ"];
     echo $textArea; //this does not work
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    welcome <?php $_POST["askerName"]; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<body>
welcome <?php echo $_POST["askerName"]; ?>
</body>
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks - that worked for all of my inputs except the <textarea>, is there a special case for that tag?

Comment: You have not give a NAME for textarea, isn't it?

Comment: Well, waiting for your new code posted.

Comment: It worked fine here. (btw your new code still forgot the echo for name)

Answer (score 0):

```
  you have to use print/echo to display your php output these two basic ways to get output: echo and print
<body>
    welcome <?php print $_POST["askerName"]; ?>
    </body>
else
<body>
welcome <?php echo $_POST["askerName"]; ?>
</body>
echo is marginally faster compared to print as echo does not return any value
```